# Perl HTTP server message MyWebServer: you can connect to your server at http://localhos t:8080

Tags: perl, http

The Perl [`HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aServer%3a%3aSimple%3a%3aCGI) sample code prints the following message:

```
Perl HTTP server message  MyWebServer: you can connect to your server at http://  localhos t:8080
```

Does this mean the http server only receive http request from localhost?

How can I make it accept http from any host?

Answer (score 0):

By default it binds to all interfaces.

However if you want to see if it really is, then you can use netstat.

```
netstat -an | grep -i listen
```

will show you what ports your machine is listening to.  You should see something like:

```
tcp4       0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

(for all interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. Actually the perl http service works for both in-bound and out-bound. There was no filter of (localhost). The problem was the I used a port, which is not http default 80. The port was blocked by my desktop's firewall.